# Access new generated content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, bind

In all the research I have found, they invoke binding an even to the element with .on(), but that not what I need. Here is a brief example:

```
<div id="myElement">
    <ul id="myUl">
        <li>content list 1</li>
        <li>content list 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After an ajax call, I replace the content of myElement using:

```
var div = $("#myElement");
div.replaceWith('<div id="myElement">
    <ul id="myUl">
        <li>new content list 1</li>
        <li>new content list 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>');
```

Now if I want to access the unordered list to add for example a class name: `div.find("ul").addClass("myClass");` it doesn't work. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The code as shown won't work even to do the replacement, because you are missing the `#` in `$("#myElement")` and your `.replaceWith()` string is not a valid string literal because of the line breaks. So how do we know the problem with later finding the `ul` isn't because of those issues or something else not shown?

Comment: You just replaced `div` with something else, it's gone, forever !

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. sorry i corrected my initial code. and it's not my origin code i just wrote a quick example :)

Comment: Well please [edit] your question to show an example that doesn't have obvious miscellaneous errors in it, so that we can concentrate on the part that you are actually having trouble with. Otherwise, further to what adeneo said, why don't you use `div.html()` to replace the div's contents rather than replacing the div itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me...

- added a # to get the element using ID
- used the ID again after replacing
- escaped the newlines
- changed className

Note you will have to do the replacement in the success of the Ajax

```js
var div = $("#myElement");
div.replaceWith('<div id="myElement">\
    <ul id="myUl">\
        <li>new content list 1</li>\
        <li>new content list 2</li>\
    </ul>\
</div>');
$("#myElement").find("ul").addClass("myClass");
console.log($("#myElement").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement">
    <ul id="myUl">
        <li>content list 1</li>
        <li>content list 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You rock man :) the solution was to just use the same ID again :)) Escaping the new lines isn't necessary